# Stubbing javascript functions with rspec and capybara-webkit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara-webkit

I'm trying to test some JS functionality with rspec and capybara-webkit.

I need to sign in with google on the client side.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>

function auth() {

      var config = {
        'client_id': '<%= ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"] %>',
        'scope': '<%= ENV["GOOGLE_APIS_HOST"] %>/auth/contacts.readonly'
      };

      gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
        fetch(gapi.auth.getToken());
      });
    }
```

With Capybara I created a fake endpoint to receive this call.

```
require "sinatra/base"
require "capybara_discoball"

class FakeGmail < Sinatra::Base
  post "/auth/contacts.readonly" do
    content_type :json

    "Return the appropriate response"
  end
end

FakeGmailRunner = Capybara::Discoball::Runner.new(FakeGmail) do |server|
  url = "http://#{server.host}:#{server.port}"
  ENV["GOOGLE_APIS_HOST"] = url
end
```

And my test looks normal

```
it "signs in with gmail", js: true do
  pool = create :pool
  user = create :user, :in_pool, pool: pool

  sign_in user
  visit pool_path(pool)
  click_on "Sign In"

  expect(page).to have_css "h1", "Welcome"
end
```

The first problem I see is that no external JS is loading (which is correct, because I want my tests to be isolated). When I access the browser console I see the following message.

```
{ :line_number=>376, :message=>"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: gapi", :source=>"http://127.0.0.1:59312/users/1" }
```

Any idea of how I could test this functionality? I need it to be on the client side because I don't have a redirect URL.

I think I need to stub `gapi` or something but it's something I don't know how to do from capybara since it's a javascript function.

Thank you

Comment: wow interesting problem. Is there any way you can fake it on this side, eg stuffing something into a local cookie then stubbing out any further calls to google?